# Cache Section of HTML Code - ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax

I have a situation where I have a page with tabs to hold multiple buttons for various functions. Each tab is for a different set of functionality (e.g. customers, orders and admin).

The way it was originally designed was I load all of the tabs and all of their buttons. The buttons shown is dependant on who is logged on.

Additionally, if a user clicks on a function it loads the code for that page, replacing the buttons in that tab as well as all of the code for the other tabs. I don't think this is very efficient and I would guess it would be better to load the content for the tabs using AJAX.

What would be the best way to accomplish this behaviour and make the code more responsive?  My thought is that I would store the html that goes inside of the tab divs in the session variables, so I would only need to get the code once when the user logs on and then just serve it back to the user based on the currently selected tab.

Answer (score 1):

To save on session you must have on your mine that:

The session data are saved all together, and read all together on the start reading of every page load, and write all together on the end of every page read. And the session lock all users, so if you add too much data and create a delay to read and write on the session, this can possible affect the users on your site. Imaging to create a big html page data that you save on session and its about 300k, and then you make the same 10 times, then the session data will be 3M that must reads and writes all the time.

So its like to add an extra data that follow the user session.

Its better if its possible to make your custom cache on a database, and save this just using the session key id, and load them only when the user enters that page, save it only when user change it.

From the other hand if you do not have many users, and you need to make it quick, or you do not have database connection, or is difficult to make a small custom cache, then use the session for one or two data of that.

Comment: @Wade73 after years of developing with asp.net, I have my custom cache, and custom session. All the feature that asp.net provides are super good, but after some time that you learn more you can change it with yours to have more control. MS have done great job, but they are general using features, so they have some small limits.